# Is it possible to retroactively get the date someone installed or first launched my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've got a feature I'd like to implement that will require me to get the date the app was first opened, or installed. For future installations, I can do that by ensuring I save the first launch date in NSUserDefaults, but is there any way to do that for those who will have already had my app installed?

Comment: I don't think so. What is the reason why you need the installation time? If you specify, maybe we can give some help...

Comment: Absolutely. My app is a simple "daily trivia" app. I've received a number of requests to allow users to use an in-app purchase to see previous facts from before they bought the app. By knowing the date they they purchased the app, I can ensure they aren't paying to see facts they have already viewed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to use NSFileManager and read the creationDate property for your Documents directory:

```
NSString *libraryDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSDictionary *fileAttributeForDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: libraryDirectory error: nil];
NSLog(@"creation date = %@", [fileAttributeForDirectory objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate]);
```